# Why does my icon font not work in IE10 on Windows 8 only?

Tags: html, css

I'm using an icon font throughout a site I have been building, and just noticed that the font does not display in IE10 on Windows 8 only.  The font works fine in IE10 on Windows 7, and in Chrome/FF across the board.

**Worth noting that SOME fonts from this set DO work in IE10/Windows 8.  E.g. '\2699'  works, but '\E744' does NOT work in IE10/Windows 8.**

**UPDATE:** Here is a JSFiddle that exhibits the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wqs5C/

Can anyone help me understand why it may not be working?

Here is the font declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons';
  src: url("../Fonts/icons.eot");
  src: url("../Fonts/icons.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url("../Fonts/icons.woff") format('woff'), 
       url("../Fonts/icons.ttf") format('truetype'), 
       url("../Fonts/icons.svg#icons") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
```

font-style: normal;
}

Here is the style (in IE10 developer tools, these have a line through them):

```
.exp_closed > .widget-head > .toggle:after {

    content: '\E744';
    font-family: 'icons';
    font-size: 16px;

}
```

Comment: seems unlikely to help, but have you tried it in lower-case -- eg `\e744` ?

Comment: @Spudley, I had not, but I just did, and the problem remains.

Comment: Are you sure you have a character with this code? Check the table of characters of this font

Comment: @Anon, I am sure, as it works in every browser/OS combination EXCEPT IE10/Windows 8.

Comment: ah well, it was worth a try. :)  Do you know which font file is being used by IE10? Is there a chance that one of your files is missing characters, and only IE10 is using that file? Also, is there any chance of putting up a demo page to show the problem?

Comment: Try using double quotes around `\E744` like this: `content: "\E744";` - that's the most common [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A%3Aafter).

Comment: (although single quotes *should* be correct too: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings )

Comment: @jfrej, That does not seem to have any effect either unfortunately.

Comment: @spudley, I have just added a JsFiddle that exhibits the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/wqs5C/

Comment: for what it's worth, that fiddle fails for me in Firefox (invalid character marker), IE10/Win7, IE11/Win7, IE10/Win8 (blank space), and IE9/Win7 (Chinese(?) character). The only browser I've tried so far where it works is Chrome (a double-arrow icon, which I guess is what is actually intended).

Comment: I get a Colon sign with FF and a double arrow with Opera. Hey, what if you put the character in the source directly, instead of referring to it in hex? I don't have IE10, so I can't test if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Spudley, Thanks for the info, I had no idea it was failing in this many browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've ultimately traced this back to "Protected Mode" in IE10.  It was preventing ALL icon fonts from working.  As soon as I disabled it, everything started acting like I'd expect it to.  The failures in FF on the JSFiddle are likely from cross-domain restrictions on font downloads.

Comment: Specifically, when you go to "custom level..." dialog under your security tab settings in internet options, you (or your IT administrator) can disable font downloading causing this unexpected behavior just on certain IE browsers